# Особенности работы функции mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Получил список таблиц из БД. Но работать с этими данными не получается.

```
$str = "show TABLEs LIKE 'dialog_".$_POST['login']."%'";
$res = mysql_query($str); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
print $row[0];

$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
print $row[0];


for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($res); $i++)
{
    print $i." ";
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    print $row[0];
}
```

Проблема в том, что этот код работает(выводится информация):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
print $row[0];

$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
print $row[0];
```

А этот нет(НЕ выводится информация):

```
for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($res); $i++)
{
    print $i." ";
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    print $row[0];
}
```

Что я делаю не так, объясните?

Comment: Изначально идёт поиск по названиям таблиц, то есть изначально названия таблиц не известны

Comment: да, этим запросом я их выбираю $str = "show TABLEs LIKE 'dialog_".$_POST['login']."%'";

Comment: row и содержит вписок выбранных таблиц

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Особенностью функции `mysql_fetch_array()` и вообще все курсорных функций является то, что они извлекая строку из результирующей таблицы продвигают курсор вперед. Поэтому если у вас в таблице лишь две записи и вы два раза вызываете `mysql_fetch_array()`, то последующие вызовы ни к чему не приводят, так как курсор указывает на конец результирующей таблицы. Для того, чтобы установить курсор в начало, вам потребуется выполнить функцию `mysql_data_seek()`.

```
$str = "show TABLEs LIKE 'dialog_".$_POST['login']."%'";
$res = mysql_query($str); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
print $row[0];

$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
print $row[0];

mysql_data_seek($res);

for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($res); $i++)
{
    print $i." ";
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    print $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)** — Обрабатывает ряд результата запроса, возвращая ассоциативный массив, численный массив или оба.Возвращает массив, соответствующий обработанному ряду результата запроса и сдвигает внутренний указатель данных вперед.
Это означает что надо пользоваться этой возможностью.То Есть бросить ее в цикл который при каждой итераций будет передвигать внутренний курсор в перед.возвращать либо данное значение либо false если курсор дошел до конца.

Без цикла,то есть присвоив ее переменной (в вашем случае) мы получим текущее одно значение массива.

Для понимания что такое курсор в массивах изучи функции [next()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.next.php),`current(),prev(),reset(),end()`

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Ошибка соединения: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Имя: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```